# Добавить колонки файла в списки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть большой файл, содержащий 3 колонки положительных чисел вида:

```
7.2 42.5 12
3 1 5.4
0.014 2 5.2
3.2 1.0 3.444
```

Необходимо для каждой колонки получить список лучшим (коротким, красивым) способом.

```
with open('input.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        pass    
        #x, y, z = line.strip() # как разделить на 3 числа здесь, а желательно и сразу добавлять?
```

Вот такое должно получаться

```
with open('input.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        data = line.split()
        x.append(float(data[0]))
        y1.append(float(data[1]))
        y2.append(float(data[2]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

L = np.array([line.split() for line in open('input.txt')])
```

В `L` получаем матрицу строки, колонки:

```
L[:,0] # первая колонка
L[:,1] # вторая колонка
L[:,2] # третья колонка
```

Comment: Так я получаю лист из строчек-листов, а надо 3 листа-колонки

Comment: @vasilis Вам матрица нужна ?

Comment: обновил вопросс

Comment: @vasilis x, y1, y2 это, что у вас такое ? пустые списки ?

Comment: да, это пустые списки

Comment: @vasilis подправил, теперь там колонки можно получить.

Comment: Можно вызвать метод `numpy.loadtxt`, он вам вернет 2-х мерную матрицу.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы порекомендовал библиотеку pandas, она специально для таких случаев и создавалась. Поэтому код займёт буквально одну строчку, не считая импорта.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('input.txt', delimiter='\t', names=['x', 'y', 'z'])

# Теперь можно обратится к любой колонке по имени
print(df.x, df.y, df.z)
```

Колонки хранятся в памяти как массивы numpy, поэтому они занимают меньше оперативки и быстрее обрабатываются, чем если бы это были простые питоновские списки.

И при этом pandas предоставляет много мощных и удобных возможностей для работы с этими данными именно как с таблицей. Очень многие задачи, например, статистики и анализа данных могут быть выполнены на таблице pandas буквально одной строчкой кода.

Answer (score 1):

```
zip(*(map(float, line.split()) for line in open('input.txt')))
```